# Pulseaudio configuration for Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

this is cross-posted from stackoverflow because I wasn't getting any answers there.
I'm trying to get sound working over Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04. I discovered that there is a default.pa file in ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#ff31e90cfd containing:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-pipe-sink sink_name=chrome_remote_desktop_session file="~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#ff31e90cfd/fifo_output" rate=48000 channels=2 format=s16le
```

When I add this file to ~/.config/pulse I have an audio device called "~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#ff31e90cfd/fifo_output" which will send sound over chrome-remote-desktop. Unfortunately, I no longer have local audio and all my regular audio devices are missing. So, I tried using an unmodified default.pa file and adding the the chrome-remote-desktop code to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# This startup script is used only if PulseAudio is started per-user
# (i.e. not in system mode)

.fail

### Automatically restore the volume of streams and devices
load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

### Automatically augment property information from .desktop files
### stored in /usr/share/application
load-module module-augment-properties

### Should be after module-*-restore but before module-*-detect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available

### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif

### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
#load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:1,0
#load-module module-oss device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-oss-mmap device="/dev/dsp" sink_name=output source_name=input
#load-module module-null-sink
#load-module module-pipe-sink

### Automatically load driver modules depending on the hardware available
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
### Use the static hardware detection module (for systems that lack udev support)
load-module module-detect
.endif

### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif

### Automatically load driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif

### Load several protocols
.ifexists module-esound-protocol-unix.so
load-module module-esound-protocol-unix
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-unix

### Network access (may be configured with paprefs, so leave this commented
### here if you plan to use paprefs)
#load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
#load-module module-zeroconf-publish

### Load the RTP receiver module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-rtp-recv

### Load the RTP sender module (also configured via paprefs, see above)
#load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp format=s16be channels=2 rate=44100 sink_properties="device.description='RTP Multicast Sink'"
#load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor

### Load additional modules from GSettings. This can be configured with the paprefs tool.
### Please keep in mind that the modules configured by paprefs might conflict with manually
### loaded modules.
.ifexists module-gsettings.so
.nofail
load-module module-gsettings
.fail
.endif


### Automatically restore the default sink/source when changed by the user
### during runtime
### NOTE: This should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
### that look up the default sink/source get the right value
load-module module-default-device-restore

### Make sure we always have a sink around, even if it is a null sink.
load-module module-always-sink

### Honour intended role device property
load-module module-intended-roles

### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
load-module module-suspend-on-idle

### If autoexit on idle is enabled we want to make sure we only quit
### when no local session needs us anymore.
.ifexists module-console-kit.so
load-module module-console-kit
.endif
.ifexists module-systemd-login.so
load-module module-systemd-login
.endif

### Enable positioned event sounds
load-module module-position-event-sounds

### Cork music/video streams when a phone stream is active
load-module module-role-cork

### Block audio recording for snap confined packages unless they have
### the "pulseaudio" or "audio-record" interfaces plugged.
.ifexists module-snap-policy.so
load-module module-snap-policy
.endif

### Modules to allow autoloading of filters (such as echo cancellation)
### on demand. module-filter-heuristics tries to determine what filters
### make sense, and module-filter-apply does the heavy-lifting of
### loading modules and rerouting streams.
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply

### Make some devices default
#set-default-sink output
#set-default-source input

### Chrome Remote Desktop
load-module module-pipe-sink sink_name=chrome_remote_desktop_session file="~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#ff31e90cfd/fifo_output" rate=48000 channels=2 format=s16le
```

I now have my regular sound devices in addition to an audio device called "~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#ff31e90cfd/fifo_output" unfortunately none of these devices sends audio over chrome-remote-desktop. They all only play locally.

Can someone help me set this up so that I can have local and remote sound? I feel like I'm very close but I'm at a loss on what to try next. Thanks!

Comment: Please check working answer here:
[sound with chrome-remote-desktop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721532/567028)

Answer (score 0):

I created `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` as follows and sound works:

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --kill
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
/usr/bin/mate-session
```

I'm using Ubuntu MATE 22.04

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem to work for me but I've largely switched over to pipewire now.